# Android. Canvas blowing animation

Tags: android, animation, svg, canvas

I am drawing svg vector image on canvas. There was fetched all  elements from svg file seperatly in List. It allows me to draw and animate each element of the picture how needed.

[image: drawing image]

The question is: How can I add blowing animation for all blue elements (something similar on hair animation [like this](https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/cdn-cgi/image/width=850/uploads/users/2073/posts/31138/image/simple-hair.gif))?
I heard something about animating besier curve, but I could not find anything about it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Take a look [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation#AnimVector) and [Shape Shifter](https://beta.shapeshifter.design/), it might be helpful

Comment: @Akaki Kapanadze Thanks for reply. I know about this instruments. In case if I would have complete svg resources for animating it will be help me.  But because of the lack of them I am asking how to do it programatically.